# Custom field implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to add "custom fields" to a sales application (Ruby 2, Rails 4, Postgres).

Here is the relevant schema:

[image: relevant database schema]

What's the best way to go about implementing this? `values` is polymorphic and `fields` is one-to-many with `accounts`.

Is there a way to loop over the fields and grab the associated value?

Answer (score 3):

I could be mistaken on what your issue is, but I think Rails is calling your `whatever-custom-field-label-is` method because it's trying to get an initial/default value for the input.

Comment: I think you're probably right. Any suggestions on how to solve this since the custom fields aren't directly part of `@sale` (or even the Sale model)?

Comment: @Dre You might be able to pass in a default value to the `text_field` method and avoid the call, but you would probably be better served by re-architecting your views to use a presenter/form decorator (check out [Reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform)).

Answer (score 1):

Using the helpers like `text_field` requires that there be a getter method for the attribute named. Rails will use that to pre populate the field.

The builtin approach to forms that span multiple models is nested attributes.

If you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :values` to your sale model then

```
= @sale.fields_for :values do |value_form|
  = value_form.label :data, value_form.object.field.label
  = value_form.text_field :data
```

Should render labels and text fields for each of your values (the block will be yielded to once for each value).

Alternatively you could eschew the rails helpers altogether.

If in instead you put in your form

```
= text_field_tag "sale[values_hash][#{v.field.label}]", v.data
```

Then it should render with no changes to the model. When the form submits `params[:sale][:values_hash]` will be a hash of the field labels to the entered values. You would need a `values_hash=` method on your model or the save would blow up. If you continue far enough down this route you'll end up with rails' nested attributes, although this may give you more control.

There are other approaches to complex forms in rails. One is to create form objects who are solely responsible for marshalling data between persistence objects and there form representation, isolating the form from having to know that attribute X is stored in a separate table and that sort of thing

Comment: The second method worked for me, thanks. But I may have phrased my initial question poorly. What would be the best way to loop over the fields themselves and populate the associated data? I am running into issues now, for example, where a new object has no `values` associated with it and nothing shows up.

Comment: With either approach you'll need to create some empty values if you want the inputs for them to render

Comment: Is that generally considered a bad practice? Is there a way to do it where `null` values aren't inserted at all? Will this cause major performance concerns down the road?

Comment: It's a fairly standard thing (although you of course wouldn't save those empty values)